# Can font-awesome icon background be transparent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

I am using a font awesome "x" icon - but it has a white background - can font-awesome backgrounds be transparent?

The reason is, I want to display it over an image.  What option do I need to do this?

Current Code is:

```
 <i class="fa fa-times fa- m-n"></i>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, font awesome uses the `::before` psuedo for its icons, so simply do, e.g.:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/LDDCf/)

```
i::before{
    background:transparent;
}
```

That said, you will likely want to use more specificity than simply `i`, e.g.:

```
i[class*=fa-times]::before{
   background:transparent;
}
```